# How can I create a rack with PCs

Tags: pc, server

Here's what I need to do:
I want to have multiple desktop/laptop PCs stored in minimal space
I should be able to attach a peripheral device to each PC.
Should be able to access the PCs easily to attach/detach peripheral devices
I would like to use a multiplexer to access each PC with the same keyboard+mouse+monitor so I save on monitor space(and wires, and cost).
It should be expandable vertically because I don't have desk space to expand horizontally.

Think of it as a Server rack, but I am not going to use individual racks. I want similar compactness but with individual PCs.
The cabinet should be secure(ie. Cabinet should be lockable)

I have searched for cabinets that allow me to store whole PCs but it doesn't look like this is easily available. Anyone who knows something that matches? or have build such cabinets?

Comment: How about just using a server rack then?  If your PC's are narrow than 19" they can lay down.  Otherwise just install shelves in the server rack, and rest the computers on top of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://thehomeserverblog.com/home-servers/diy-19-server-rack-for-home-servers-and-or-esxi-vmware-lab/

Material List for D.I.Y. Server Rack

```
2 Pair of 20U Space Rack Rails — $45 (eBay)
4 2x4s – $10.00 (Lowe’s)
48 3″ Sheetrock Screws — $4.58 (Lowe’s)
20 1-1/4″ Sheetrock Screws — $4.58 (Lowe’s)
Set of 4 2″ High Capacity Rubber Locking Plate Casters – $15.99 (Amazon)
Minwax Wood Finish, Red Oak 215 (had some)
```

Total Cost: $80.15

Tool List for D.I.Y. Server Rack

```
Saw (Circular, Table, or Radial; I have a Sliding, Compound Radial Saw)
Cordless Drill (Mine: B&D 18v)
Phillips Head bit (magnetic is a plus)
Drill bit (for pilot holes for the screw)
Paint brush for Minwax
```

Steps for D.I.Y. Home Server Rack

```
Make cuts on 2x4s (see above for cuts)
Assemble top and bottom “square frames”
Attach uprights to bottom frame (use a square to make sure these are square/level)
Attach Rails, making sure they are flush again the bottom frame, and square along the edge.
Attach top square frame
Stain (this is optional, but easy and makes it look nice)
Attach casters to bottom of server rack.
```